# Как удалить элемент со страницы средствами jQuery или JS?

Tags: jquery, javascript

```
<div class="fox-copyright" style="padding:10px 0 !important;text-indent:0 !important"><a target="_blank" title="Joomla contact form" href="http://www.fox.ra.it/" style="visibility: visible !important; display: inline !important; font-size:10px !important;">powered  by fox contact</a></div>
```

Пытаюсь удалить div.fox-copyright со страницы со всем его содержимым - пробовал использовать методы jquery - remove(), detach() и empty(), но ничего не работает. Почему так? Как удалить элемент div.fox-copyright и все его содержимое?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[@eprivalov1](/users/6953/eprivalov1)](/users/6953/eprivalov1), автор ничего не шаманил. html-код страницы (то, что вы видите, когда нажимаете "Посмотреть код страницы") это то, что пришло с сервера. DOM-дерево (document object model) - то, что вы видите в консоли браузера, это совсем другая степь. С помощью jquery, javascript-a вы манипулируете DOM-деревом, а не кодом страницы.

Answer (score 3):

Плохо пытаетесь :)

```
$('.fox-copyright').remove();
```

Пример: http://jsfiddle.net/Lmuna49f/

**И копирайты прятать не хорошо :3**

Comment: Прятать, это если в css задать display: none; это нехорошо, а вот удалять норм.

Comment: `$('.fox-copyright').remove();` - почему-то не удаляет хтмл код со страницы, хотя в консоли ошибок нет.

Comment: @eprivalov1 в примере ведь удаляет. :) jQuery точно подключен?

Comment: @Bastian jQuery 100% включен, я уже удалил html код из вывода в PHP файле. С помощью jQuery и JavaScript никак не получается удалить. Видимо, автор плагина что-то нашаманил, чтоб ссылки не удаляли.